# How to highlight some options of ngb-typeahead based on a condition?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead, ngb-typeahead

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#focus

In this demo, I have to make the dropdown options with value which starts with 'M' and 'N' to be permanently highlighted with green and rest with yellow. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done my joining lots of different CSS concept together first go down to element by using ng:deep, then add regex to parameter of attribute which contains text.

```
::ng-deep .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item  ngb-highlight[ng-reflect-result^='M'] {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

I have edited a stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewpbua?file=src/app/typeahead-focus.css).